# Validation Messages is not visible when using an EditForm with custom Wizard Component

Tags: c#, blazor, wizard, validationmessage, blazor-editform

I have followed tutorial below how to create a simple wizard component in Blazor Webbassembly, so far so good.

https://sinclairinat0r.com/2019/12/08/creating-a-simple-wizard-component-in-blazor

But when I try to put the wizard inside an Edit form like below i run into a problem.

```
  @page "/wizarddemo"
    
    <EditForm Model="@wizardViewModel" OnValidSubmit="@OnValidSubmit" OnInvalidSubmit="@OnInvalidSubmit">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    
        <Wizard Id="DemoWizard" @ref="wizard">
            <WizardStep StepModel="firstStepModel" Name="First Step">
    
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="label">First name</label><span style="color:red;">*</span>
                    <InputText id="companyName" class="form-control" type="text" @bind-Value="@firstStepModel.FirstName"></InputText>
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => firstStepModel.FirstName)" />
                </div>
    
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="label">Last name</label><span style="color:red;">*</span>
                    <InputText id="companyName" class="form-control" type="text" @bind-Value="@firstStepModel.LastName"></InputText>
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => firstStepModel.LastName)" />
                </div>
    
            </WizardStep>
            <WizardStep StepModel="companyModel" Name="Second Step">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="label"Company</label><span style="color:red;">*</span>
                    <InputText id="companyName" class="form-control" type="text" @bind-Value="@companyModel.CompanyName"></InputText>
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => companyModel.CompanyName)" />
                </div>
    
    
            </WizardStep>
            <WizardStep StepModel="countryModel" Name="Final Step">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="label">Country</label><span style="color:red;">*</span>
                            <select id="country" class="form-control selectpicker" @bind="countryModel.CountryId">
                                <option value="">--select a country--</option>
                                @foreach (var country in countries)
                                {
                                    <option value="@country.Id">@country.Name</option>
                                }
                            </select>
                            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => countryModel.CountryId)" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </WizardStep>
        </Wizard>
    </EditForm>
```

Code behind

```
    public Wizard wizard;
    protected EditForm editForm;

    private FirstStepModel firstStepModel;

    private CountryModel countryModel;

    private CompanyModel companyModel;

    private WizardViewModel wizardViewModel;

    private List<Country> countries = new List<Country>();

    public string StatusMessage { get; set; }

    public string StatusClass { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        wizardViewModel = new WizardViewModel();
        wizardViewModel.CountryModel = new CountryModel();
        wizardViewModel.CompanyModel = new CompanyModel();
        wizardViewModel.FirstStepModel = new FirstStepModel();

        countryModel = new CountryModel();
        companyModel = new CompanyModel();
        firstStepModel = new FirstStepModel();

        countries.Add(new Country { Id = 1, Name = "Sweden" });
        countries.Add(new Country { Id = 2, Name = "england" });

    }

    private async Task OnValidSubmit()
    {
        StatusClass = "alert-info";
        StatusMessage = DateTime.Now + " Handle valid submit";
        wizard.ActiveStep.StepCompleted = true;
    }

    private async Task OnInvalidSubmit()
    {
        StatusClass = "alert-danger";
        StatusMessage = DateTime.Now + " Handle invalid submit";
        wizard.ActiveStep.StepCompleted = false;
    }

    public class Country
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class CountryModel
    {
        [Required]
        public int? CountryId { get; set; }
    }

    public class CompanyModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    }

    public class FirstStepModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public class WizardViewModel
    {
        public FirstStepModel FirstStepModel { get; set; }

        public CountryModel CountryModel { get; set; }

        public CompanyModel CompanyModel { get; set; }

    }
```

}

The problem is that the "ValidationMessage" component does not trigger (or is visible) when I click on the "next" button in the wizzard or when I click inside the empty "InputText" for firstStepModel.FirstName and leave it empty then click on the "InputText" field for firstStepModel.LastName and type a name iside that field.

But when I then again click inside the "InputText" field for FirstName type a name and then remove the name and click outside the InputText field then the ValidationMessages appears.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOEiO.png)

The rest of the code looks like this.

Wizard.razor

Wizard.razor.cs

```
public partial class Wizard
{
    /// <summary>
    /// List of <see cref="WizardStep"/> added to the Wizard
    /// </summary>
    protected internal List<WizardStep> Steps = new List<WizardStep>();

    /// <summary>
    /// The control Id
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public Object CurrentStepModelObject { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The ChildContent container for <see cref="WizardStep"/>
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Active <see cref="WizardStep"/>
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public WizardStep ActiveStep { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Index number of the <see cref="ActiveStep"/>
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public int ActiveStepIx { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the Wizard is in the last step
    /// </summary>

    public bool IsLastStep { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the <see cref="ActiveStep"/> to the previous Index
    /// </summary>

    protected internal void GoBack()
    {
        if (ActiveStepIx > 0)
            SetActive(Steps[ActiveStepIx - 1]);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the <see cref="ActiveStep"/> to the next Index
    /// </summary>
    protected internal void GoNext()
    {
        bool defaultValidatorSuccess = CheckValidationStatus(CurrentStepModelObject);

        if (defaultValidatorSuccess)
        {
            ActiveStep.StepCompleted = true;
        }

        if (ActiveStepIx == Steps.Count - 1 && ActiveStep.StepCompleted)
        {

            if (defaultValidatorSuccess)
            {
                ActiveStep.StatusClass = "alert-info";
                ActiveStep.StatusMessage = DateTime.Now + " Handle valid submit";
                // last step, try save to database...
            }
            else
            {
                ActiveStep.StatusClass = "alert-danger";
                ActiveStep.StatusMessage = DateTime.Now + " Handle invalid submit";
            }
        }

        if (ActiveStepIx < Steps.Count - 1 && ActiveStep.StepCompleted)
        {
            SetActive(Steps[(Steps.IndexOf(ActiveStep) + 1)]);
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool CheckValidationStatus(Object obj)
    {
        //if all fields is ok
        ValidationContext ctx = new ValidationContext(obj);

        List<ValidationResult> results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        bool _defaultvalidatorSuccess = Validator.TryValidateObject(obj, ctx, results);

        return _defaultvalidatorSuccess;
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Populates the <see cref="ActiveStep"/> the Sets the passed in <see cref="WizardStep"/> instance as the
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="step">The WizardStep</param>
    protected internal void SetActive(WizardStep step)
    {
        ActiveStep = step ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(step));

        CurrentStepModelObject = ActiveStep.StepModel;

        ActiveStepIx = StepsIndex(step);
        if (ActiveStepIx == Steps.Count - 1)
            IsLastStep = true;
        else
            IsLastStep = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the index of the current <see cref="WizardStep"/> in the Step List
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="step">The WizardStep</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public int StepsIndex(WizardStep step) => StepsIndexInternal(step);
    protected int StepsIndexInternal(WizardStep step)
    {
        if (step == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(step));

        return Steps.IndexOf(step);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a <see cref="WizardStep"/> to the WizardSteps list
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="step"></param>
    protected internal void AddStep(WizardStep step)
    {
        Steps.Add(step);
    }

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            SetActive(Steps[0]);
            ActiveStep.StepCompleted = false;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        CurrentStepModelObject = new object();
    }
```

WizardStep.razor

```
  @if (Parent.ActiveStep == this)
    {
        <div class="alert @StatusClass">@StatusMessage</div>
        <div id="step-@(Parent.StepsIndex(this) + 1)">
            @ChildContent
        </div>
    }
```

WizardStep.razor.cs

```
public partial class WizardStep
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="Wizard"/> container
    /// </summary>
    [CascadingParameter]
    protected internal Wizard Parent { get; set; }

    public string StatusMessage { get; set; }

    public string StatusClass { get; set;}

    [Parameter]
    public object StepModel { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Child Content of the current <see cref="WizardStep"/>
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Name of the step
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool StepCompleted { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Parent.AddStep(this);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea of what's wrong with the code?